# "Issue of" or "Issue out of"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

1. Don't make an issue of inconsequential things.
2. Don't make an issue out of inconsequential things.

Which of them is right and why?

Comment: They're both fine, but [including "**out**" is relatively uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+an+issue+out+of%2Cmake+an+issue+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20an%20issue%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20an%20issue%20of%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Either is right, I'd you advise you not to make an issue out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is correct because "inconsequential things" is sufficiently defined. An example where the other would be correct might be, "Don't make an issue out of nothing."